# ascx file not opening in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ascx

I am trying to edit an ascx file from our server to modify some aspects of our website. However, when I import the ascx into Visual Studio, instead of code I get weird lines of text that look like memory addresses. See below:

```
00000000  AA 2A 81 C2 98 3E 6D E6  4C DB 0A 81 9B 6D 3B 37  .*...>m.l....m;7
00000010  20 E1 66 7F D1 B5 C3 A5  8D 57 7J 7F FF 33 23 83   .f......Wv..3#.
```

... And this goes on for quite some time. I suspect there is a fundemental point I am missing here about ascx files and Visual Studio. I am obviously new to modifying ascx files, can somebody lead me in the right direction so I can edit the code?

Comment: Try a text editor. Although it appears to be a binary file.

Comment: ascx files are text based so whatever your viewing may have a .ascx file extension but it's not actually an ascx file.  Looks like a binary file to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments helped me with, the solution to this problem is that the .ascx files are binary even though they have the .ascx extension. Editable files should always be able to be viewed in Notepad, and especially in Visual Studio.